# How to use $lookup in mongodb on ObjectIds

Tags: java, mongodb

I have 2 collections, one referencing to the other by a foreign ObjectId.
I'm trying to performe a $lookup on the 2 collections.
The thing is the foreign ObjectId is saved as a document with the below format :

`"testId" : { "timestamp" : 1469105907, 
    "machineIdentifier" : 8036392, 
    "processIdentifier" : 7899, 
    "counter" : 12372063, 
    "timeSecond" : 1469105907, 
    "time" : NumberLong("1469105907000"), 
    "date" : NumberLong("1469105907000") 
    }`

While the ObjectId the above is refering to is in this format :

```
ObjectId("5790c6437aa0281e0f534729")
```

how do i save de foreign ObjecId with the sae format as the one is refering to ?

I use java driver and mongo 3.2.0 !!!
And saving the Document as below :

```
Test at = new Test();
        at.setForeignId(new ObjectId("5790c6437aa0281e0f534729"));
```

Comment: Why do use such format to refer foreign testId, can you store it just as the ObjectId? Your testId document resembles information that constitutes the ObjectId, see documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry !
The problem was in the document insertion. I was using a mapper object wich was rendering the ObjectId this way. !!! 
**don't use this :**

```
 org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString( POJO_OBJECT );
        Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);
```

I had to reconfigure the whole insertion process by creating a document the way below :

```
Document doc = new Document();
    doc.append("_id", POJO_OBJECT.theObjectId);
    doc.append("foreign", POJO_OBJECT.theForeignId);
    doc.append("objectOne", POJO_OBJECT.objectOne);
    doc.append("objectTwo", POJO_OBJECT.objectTwo);
    ...
```

and then use this doc for insertion !!!! hope that save somefolks of that **headache**